# When the JavaScript is within the html it works when it outside it doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, external-js

I use the following JavaScript .. when it is written inside the html file it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var d=new Date();
        var ShowenYear = d.getFullYear();
        var Month = d.getMonth();
        var NextSeason = "Unknown Season";

        if (Month == 1 || Month == 2 || Month == 3) {
            NextSeason = "Spring";
        }
        else if (Month == 4 || Month == 5 || Month == 6) {
            NextSeason = "Summer";
        }
            else if (Month == 7 || Month == 8 || Month == 9) {
                NextSeason = "Autumn";
            }
                else if (Month == 10 || Month == 11 || Month == 12) {
                    NextSeason = "Winter";
                    ShowenYear++;
                    }
        
        document.getElementById("Season").innerHTML = NextSeason + " " + ShowenYear;
    </script>
```

It works perfectly fine, but when I created a js file copied it all (exact same just without the script tag.

Then called the file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/showdate.js" ></script>
```

it simply doesn't work.

Comment: It would help to paste your exact HTML code when you're loading the file, and the exact path to your file. Also, is the file loaded correctly? You can see that by developer tools or the console in Chrome.

Comment: wrap all your code inside `window.onload`

Comment: any errors? what means: "it simply doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/showdate.js"></script>
```

try to write this line of code inside the `<head>` tags. Then add `<body onload="showdate();">` so that the function is called everytime the page loads.

```
    function showdate(){
    var d=new Date();
            var ShowenYear = d.getFullYear();
            var Month = d.getMonth();
            var NextSeason = "Unknown Season";

            if (Month == 1 || Month == 2 || Month == 3) {
                NextSeason = "Spring";
            }
            else if (Month == 4 || Month == 5 || Month == 6) {
                NextSeason = "Summer";
            }
                else if (Month == 7 || Month == 8 || Month == 9) {
                    NextSeason = "Autumn";
                }
                    else if (Month == 10 || Month == 11 || Month == 12) {
                        NextSeason = "Winter";
                        ShowenYear++;
                        }

            document.getElementById("Season").innerHTML = NextSeason + " " + ShowenYear;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you giving proper `src`

Comment: Did you remove the <script> tags in showdate.js ? And I edited my answer, I wrote a wrong src in your case.

Comment: @user2737192 Open your page in Google Chrome and press `F12` It'll show error if any on right side bottom of the page..

Comment: I did remove the script tag and i the src code is the way it should be

Comment: Could you post your full showdate.js code, and the html part related to this?